# DevOps App Center Distribute Task gives Unauthorised error

Tags: xamarin.forms, devops, visual-studio-app-center, unauthorized

I have 2 tasks in my Release Pipeline in DevOps. One distributes the Android package (Xamarin Forms) to App Center, which is working fine. The second distributes the iOS package (Xamarin Forms), also to App Center, but has stopped working in the last few days.

The error I get now is on the Distribute task is: Unauthorised. Correlation ID: ...http response code: 401

Why am I getting Unauthorised errors for 1 task and not the other, and how to I know who/what isn't authorised?

Comment: I created a new API Token in App Center in the Settings for the app, and tried to redeploy, but got  the same error

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. It was the token in the App Center